# Writing a service to keep two folder in sync?

Tags: windows, synchronization, directory

I need to keep synchronized two folder on different host in Windows. I really think that something already done exists but I did not find anything (SyncToys is not an option), do you have something to suggest me?

Requirements are:

- running as a service
- sync over a network shared path (ie `\\myhost\myfolder`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say use rsync with task scheduler to accomplish what you're wanting.

There are several ports of rsync to windows, you might check out the following:

- [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp)
- [cwrsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650)

Comment: I will try to replace my solution with cwrsync, thanks

Answer (score 1):

After a long search, I found [SuperFlexible](http://www.superflexible.com/).  Maybe that's the answer - and it doesn't cost much.

Comment: well I did one myself, so in order to evaluating a new one I prfefer an OpenSource c#

Comment: maybe it would help if you put that into the question - you didn't state that you want SOURCE at all

Answer (score 0):

**Real Time Folder Synchronization Window Service**

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35632/Real-Time-Folder-Synchronization-Window-Service

Code source http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/FileSync/FileSyncService_source.zip

Answer (score 0):

Free, Open-Source, Cross-Platform, Web-Based GUI, P2P+UPNP discovery:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncthing

Can run as a Windows service using the Free & Open-Source tool NSSM:
http://nssm.cc/download

Here's how:
https://docs.syncthing.net/users/autostart.html