# How to programmatically setup an incremental mirroring service using Java / .NET

Tags: backup, replication, mirroring

I would like to replicate / mirror a shared file system location across several mirrors. Is there any .NET / Java library to do so? or even any out of the box solution (open source prefered so we can customize it)

It should be

1. Free
2. Lightwieight
3. Open Source prefered
4. Incremental
5. Can be one way (mirroring only)

Comment: are you defining your own virtual filesystem on each host, or trying to synchronize the contents of the existing filesystem?

Comment: here a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813884/writing-a-service-to-keep-two-folder-in-sync

Comment: @Greg - existing file systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't you just use DFS? It's free with the Windows OS.

Comment: I used xcopy on a scheduled task, the best and easiest solution