# C# folder sync library

Tags: c#, synchronization, directory

I'm looking for an easy to use library/algorithm that can sync two folders locally (one-way or two-way)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing a service to keep two folder in sync ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813884/writing-a-service-to-keep-two-folder-in-sync)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753).

There is a guide for syncing files at [How to: Synchronize Files by Using Managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617386.aspx).

Comment: Any idea why that second link is embedded inside SQL Server 2008 R2?! Seems an oversight on Microsoft's part as it doesn't have anything to do with databases, or at the very least SQL Server.

Comment: @Dan: I don't know, took me a couple of seconds to realise that it appears to be an error on MSDN's part.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one of many examples available by googling ["C# Folder Sync"](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=C%23+folder+sync)

[**Real Time Folder Synchronization Window Service**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/FileSync.aspx)

Comment: Can this sync between 2 logical drives?