# Copy only files that are newer

Tags: c#, copy

I am currently using this code:

```
    if (!Directory.Exists(command2)) Directory.CreateDirectory(command2);

    if (Directory.Exists(vmdaydir)) Directory.Delete(vmdaydir,true);

    if (!Directory.Exists(vmdaydir)) Directory.CreateDirectory(vmdaydir);

    var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(args[0]);

    sb.AppendLine("Backing Up VM: " + DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(dir, vmdaydir);
    sb.AppendLine("VM Backed Up: " + DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

As you can see, I am deleting the directory, then I am copying the folder back. This is taking way to long since the directory is ~80gb in size. I realized that I do not need to copy all the files, only the ones that have changed.

How would I copy the files from one folder to another but only copying the files that are newer?  Anyone have any suggestions?

==== edit ====

I assume I can just do a file compare of each file and then copy it to the new directory, iterating through each folder/file?  Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: `CreateDirectory` will  create it only if it does not exist so the check is redundant.

Comment: Have you looked at this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506235/c-sharp-folder-sync-library

Comment: Changed since when? You'll need to cache each file's last write date before that logic takes place.. are you doing that currently?

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks Tim I will adjust accordingly.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead You see what I'm doing. I'm not checking anything...

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin I don't want to sync them, I just want to copy it over. Does the sync framework handle one way syncing?

Comment: Do you do this occassionally or would it better suit you if your application is constantly running and monitoring the directory for any changes?

Comment: @ErocM Sure, it supports one-way sync, but in your case it doesn't really matter unless you are making changes to your backup files. However MS Sync Framework is quite tricky to use so if you need a simple one time solution probably that is not the way to go

Comment: @user1556110 I only need it to do it once a day at a specific time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the FileInfo class, and use the LastWriteTime property to get the last modified time of the file.  Compare it to the time you're checking against and take only files that are later.

Loop through the files in the directory, checking the last modified time (FileInfo.LastWriteTime) - any files that are newer are copied over.

See [FileInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: yeah that's what I figured... I'm looking at doing this now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful when trying to do this that you can get a lock on the file otherwise another application may not be finished with it and you may try to copy it before you are ready.

So follow these steps...

1) attempt to lock file

2) if(got lock) copy file

3) else wait a short time

4) goto 1

:)

Comment: my supervisor would shoot me for even mentioning the word goto :P

Comment: lol, tell your supervisor that goto has a great function in coding. In use in learning how to code, but yeah... goto = a big no no :)