# Sync two directories (update target dir from source dir) in C# / .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I want to sync two directories, such that after the operation the target dir is an exact copy of the source dir. New source files / sub directories are added to the target, newer source files replace the older target versions, files missing in the source get deleted from the target.

I know I can recursively go through both trees, check for existence and compare last write dates.

**My question:** Is there something out of the box I can use instead of writing my own code? Something like `TargetDir.UpdateFromSourceDir(SourceDir);` :-)

I found **System.DirectoryServices** with the **DirectorySynchronization** class here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysynchronization?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0. From its name it sounds like it might do what I want, but from its methods I doubt that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# folder sync library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506235/c-sharp-folder-sync-library)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.copydirectory?view=net-5.0

Comment: @Charlieface: Thank you. This does look good.I can't make out, though, how to use it. They mention FileSyncProvider and SyncOrchestrator, but don't say what assemblies to include and what using directive is needed. Can you shed some light on this?

Comment: @Hans Passant: Thank you. This just seems to overwrite all target files with all source files with brute force (not checking if the target files aren't already current) and I don't think that files get removed from target when they no longer exist in source.

Comment: The easiest way to do this without mistakes, is to delete and copy the directory. If you don't want that, the safest way (albeit prone to more data races)  is to hash all the files, make a list of files to remove, add, update. The unsafest way is to do the above but instead use last modified date and time. Personally id just delete and copy and move on to something else

Comment: @00110001: Thanks. My main concern is speed. The dates would suffice for my case. The problem is that the source directory is on some server that I access with a drive letter (like G:) in Windows, but access to the files is awfully slow. So the idea is to copy the directories I need once to C: and later just check on the directory dates, whether I need an update. And if I need one, I just want to copy the few changes, nothing more.

Comment: I found the directive `using Microsoft.Synchronization;`, but there is no Microsoft.Synchronization available in the references nor via NuGet it seems. I tried to install Microsoft.SyncFramework for that sounded promising, but get the error that this cannot be done, as this needs a framework link to Microsoft.Synchronization which is not in GAC. "Maybe an error in the packet" they say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been recommended to use the Microsoft Sync Framework. I got the `Microsoft.SyncFramework` via NuGet, but get the error that `Microsoft.Synchronization` is not available. I interpret this to mean that the library is based on another library that doesn't exist anymore.

As my program will only run under Windows, I found a simple solution here: https://serverfault.com/questions/154324/how-do-i-mirror-a-folder-copy-only-missing-and-changed-files-recursively-in-wi. The idea is to run the command line tool robocopy.exe that ships with Windows and does exactly what I want (using the option /MIR).

```
using (Process RoboCopyProcess = new Process())
{
  RoboCopyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "robocopy.exe";
  RoboCopyProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = SourceDirPath + " " + TargetDirPath + " /MIR";
  RoboCopyProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  RoboCopyProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
  RoboCopyProcess.Start();
  RoboCopyProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are as many ways to do this as lines of code in the example I will show.

- The easiest way is to use a sync library
- Failing that, is to delete and copy the directory.
- If you don't want that, the safest way (albeit prone to more data races) is to hash all the files, make a list of files to remove, add, update.
- The riskiest way is to do the above but instead use file date

Personally I'd just delete and copy and move on to something else, however you could try this.

<sub>***Forewarning** : Use a sync library if you can find one. This is purely for academic purposes and doesn't equate to the worlds best solution.*</sub>

**Given**

```
public static (HashSet<string> dirs, HashSet<(string file,long tick)> files) Get(string dir)
{

   string CleanPath(string path) => path.Substring(dir.Length).TrimStart('/', '\\');

   // replace this with a hashing method if you need
   long GetUnique(string path) => new FileInfo(path).LastWriteTime.Ticks;

   var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

   var dirHash = directories.Select(CleanPath).ToHashSet();

   // this could be paralleled if need be (if using a hash) 
   var fileHash = directories.SelectMany(Directory.EnumerateFiles)
      .Select(file => (name: CleanPath(file), ticks : GetUnique(file)))
      .ToHashSet();

   return (dirHash, fileHash);    
}
```

**Usage**

```
var result1 = Get(dir1);
var result2 = Get(dir2);

var dirsToRemove = result2.dirs.Where(x => !result1.dirs.Contains(x));
var filesToRemove = result2.files.Where(x => !result1.files.Contains(x));
var filesToAdd = result1.files.Where(x => !result2.files.Contains(x));

foreach (var fileToRemove in filesToRemove)
   Console.WriteLine("Deleting : " + Path.Combine(dir2, fileToRemove.file));

foreach (var dirToRemove in dirsToRemove)
   Console.WriteLine("Deleting : " + Path.Combine(dir2, dirToRemove));

foreach (var fileToAdd in filesToAdd)
   Console.WriteLine("Adding : " + Path.Combine(dir2,fileToAdd.file));
```

<sub>***Note** : There are many ways for this to fail, the assumption is you have permissions to do this and files aren't locked. This also should have a significant amount of error checking, may need to be customized, and you should use an extreme amount of due diligence before you use it (be warned).*</sub>

Comment: Wow, thank you for putting so much effort into this. I have not been able to find a sync library. I suppose that the recommended Microsoft library doesn't exist anymore. I like your approach and learned a lot from it. Thank you.